# How to add specific x ticks, labels and vertical lines to a plot using Plots.jl?

Tags: plot, julia

I am trying to add to a plot two vertical lines with the corresponding ticks and labels on the x axis to highlight important points.

I found two approaches (A and B that follows), but in the first one the new ticks/labels replace rather than append the old ones, and in the second approach the labels are printed in somehow inconsistent locations (depending on the range) and can't get them where I want them to be:

```
using Plots, StatPlots, DataFrames
pyplot()
df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = 10*rand(10), c = 10 * rand(10))
f = Plots.font("DejaVu Sans", 10)
@df df plot(:a, [:b :c], label=["serie a" "serie b"], xtickfont=f, ytickfont=f, legendfont=f, guidefont=f, titlefont=f)
```

**A:**

```
plot!([5,7], seriestype="vline", xticks = ([5,7],["\$\\bar \\delta \$","\$\\bar \\gamma \$"]), label="")
```

This show up like:
[image: screenshot of A]

**B:**

```
plot!([5], seriestype="vline", label="")
annotate!(5, 0, text("\$ \\bar \\delta \$",f, :bottom, :left))
plot!([7], seriestype="vline", label="")
annotate!(7, 0, text("\$\\bar \\gamma \$",f, :top)
```

This show up like:
[image: screenshot of B]

Comment: If I know the data a priori I can build the whole set of xticks and xlabels, adding the wonted ones, but how to get the xticks and xlabels fro mthe current plot ?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to grab the `xticks` from your original plot and merge them with the `xticks` that you want. Below is a MWE close to your example

```
using Plots, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(a = 1:10, b = 10rand(10), c = 10rand(10))
plt = plot(df.a, [df.b df.c], label=["serie a" "serie b"])
old_xticks = xticks(plt[1]) # grab xticks of the 1st subplot
new_xticks = ([5, 8], ["\$\\bar \\delta\$", "\$\\bar \\gamma\$"])
vline!(new_xticks[1])
keep_indices = findall(x -> all(x .≠ new_xticks[1]), old_xticks[1])
merged_xticks = (old_xticks[1][keep_indices] ∪ new_xticks[1], old_xticks[2][keep_indices] ∪ new_xticks[2])
xticks!(merged_xticks)
```

and produces

[image]

Note that I purposefully moved your index `7` to `8` so that I had to be careful to remove the original xtick there, so that this solution is a bit more general.

Also note that ticks-getter functions like `xticks` were added in [Plots.jl v1.13.0](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/releases/tag/v1.13.0).